# Подскажите ,что мне исправить ,чтобы программа работала корректно

Tags: c#

В общем, пишу прогу на языке c# , условия данной проги "Найти числа < 50,после чего перемножить их и найти числа >100 , после чего слоить их, если таких числе нет, то вывести на Textbox "Элементов не найднено", мой код который я написал, находит данные числа и выполняет все условия, но если он не находит данные числа, т.е. число <50 или число >100 , то он выводит первоначальное "proz", " sum", в чем заключается моя ошибка и что нужно исправить, буду очень благодарен за адекватный ответ.
Мой код:

```cs
int count = A_TB.Lines.Length;
int[] mas = new int[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(A_TB.Lines[i]);
}
int proz = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (mas[i] < 50)
    {
        proz *= mas[i];
    }
    else
    { 
        B_TB.Text = "Элементов не найдено"; 
    }
}
B_TB.Text = Convert.ToString(proz);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (mas[i] > 100)
    {
        sum += mas[i];
    }
    else
    { 
        C_TB.Text = "Элементов не найдено";
    }
}
C_TB.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

После обоих ифов у тебя стоят команды вывода:
`B_TB.Text = Convert.ToString(proz);` - после первого ифа
`C_TB.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);` - после второго ифа
Они выполняются независимо от условия. Потому и выводит :)

Comment: А не подскажешь ,как это исправить , а то я чет уже 2-ой час сижу, туплю